# I want to display the previous data instead of empty list if connection is lost

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I want to store the previous monthly event data in a variable and display in case of unsuccessful response call , as of now it is displaying empty list, please suggest me how we can do that

```java
//this loads events for month view
public void loadEvents(int year, int month) {
    RetrofitEvent.getEventApi().getEvents(year, month, userName).enqueue(new Callback<List<Event>>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Event>> call, Response<List<Event>> response) {
            if ((!response.isSuccessful()) || response.body() == null) {
                eventsLiveData.setValue(Collections.emptyList());
                return;
            }
            Log.d("MyFitness229789", "posting value: " + response.body().size() + " <- size");

            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Collections.sort(response.body(), getComparator());
                    eventsLiveData.postValue(response.body());
                    Log.d("MyFitness229789", "posting value: " + response.body().size());
                    for (Event event :
                            response.body()) {
                        Log.d("MyFitness229789", "run: " + event.toString());
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Event>> call, Throwable t) {
            eventsLiveData.setValue(Collections.emptyList());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: eventsLiveData is holding the value for the list. It seems like onFailure() is called when the connection is lost and that drives your eventsLiveData to be empty. So please either remove setting value the empty list in onFailure() or using room for stable data handling

Comment: If you `I want to store the previous monthly event data ` why do you set emptyList to eventsLiveData ? Or you what cache last successful response for year and month to cases when user what to see previous month and ` RetrofitEvent.getEventApi().getEvents` return error ?